# why my hyperlink tags display as plain text on the browser?

Tags: html, href

In a table structure, I add a hyperlink like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <a href='http://www.google.com'>link</a>
    </tr>
</table>
```

But it display as plain text on the browser(IE or firefox) like this:

```
<a href='www.google.com'>link</a>
```

not a **link point**.

who can tell me the reason? thankx.

Comment: yes, my above code is right. What I want to know is "Why the link be displayed as plain text", and how can I fix it. that's what I want to know.

Comment: Are you able to click the link and navigate to the page?

Comment: may be you named the file .txt

Answer (score 3):

Two items. As treaschf noted you need to use double quotes, and for any link leaving your site you need to preface it with http://

```
<table>    
    <tr>        
        <td>
            <a href="http://www.google.com">link</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I don't think that there will be any difference in setting the attribute values in double quotes rather than giving it in single quotes.

Comment: Unlike treaschf's reply, this one fixes all the problems in the HTML snippet.

Comment: Technically, single quotes are fine according to both HTML 4 and XHTML.  See http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-AttValue  That said, I trust web browsers to follow standards about as much as I trust politicians to follow their campaign promises.  Use double quotes.

Comment: But even if he doesn't give the http:// the link should work but won't point to the correct location.

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
<table>    
    <tr>        
        <td>
            <a href="http://www.google.com">link</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Don't forget to prepend "http://" to the URL, else it'd be relative to the current site.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the TD element so the HTML is invalid. Pass your HTML through the [HTML Validator](http://validator.w3.org/).